# Stripe.js Keep Multiple Payment Tokens

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, stripe-payments

I've been able to implement Stripe.js into the client-side (javascript, angularjs, jquery) code of my app, as well as the back end (c#, web api) using Stripe.net. But, I've run into a question that doesn't seem to be answered anywhere that I can find.

When we charge a user for an item in our app, the may want to come back later and purchase another one without having to re-enter credit card information. Therefor, we're creating a customer object through stripe to store the credit card token on.

My question is, is there some way to store multiple tokens on a single customer object, so that we can re-use the same payment info, but also allow a customer to have multiple forms of payment? Should I be creating a new customer for each form of payment, and storing their id's on my customer's user model?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single customer can definitely have more than one payment source.

You can [create cards](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card) or [bank accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_create_bank_account) to add them as payment sources to an existing customer.

When you [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) using the [`customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-customer) parameter only, the customer's default source will be charged. If you want to charge a non-default source, you need to use both the [`customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-customer) parameter (set to the customer's ID) and the [`source`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-source) parameter (set to the card's or bank account's ID).

In order to change the default source for a customer, you need to [update the customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer) with the ID of the new default source in the [`default_source`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer-default_source) parameter.